# How do you add an ImageView to a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Normally using a ListView adding images and text to the ListView items is straight forward. You create and adapter and setListAdapter(adapter) with your custom adapter.

I would like to create a Fragment app that contains the same list with ImageView.  I have searched for an example but have not been able to find any that have an image.  Can someone please point me to an example so I can see how it is done?

Is it done in the layout-land XML? How would you declare that using the following xml for example.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.demo.android.FragmentLayout$ArticleFragment"
            android:id="@+id/article" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a class the extends `Fragment` or `ListFragment`, then inflate the layout the contains your `ListView` and set your `Adapter`.

**Example `ListFragment`:**

```
public class Example extends ListFragment {

// Adapter
private YourListAdapter mAdapter;

// ListView
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Adapter
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aneal, I think I am making things too complicated for myself.  I took the same approach as you would using a listview and that worked for me.